# Most efficient method of finding a model by ID with Model.find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, performance

I noticed that I can do a `Model.find` in a number of ways (assuming @user is an instance of the User model):

```
User.find(2)
=> #<User id: 2, name: "Mike Swift", email: "valid@email.com", ... etc ...
```

OR

```
User.find(@user)
=> #<User id: 2, name: "Mike Swift", email: "valid@email.com", ... etc ...
```

OR

```
User.find(@user[:id])
=> #<User id: 2, name: "Mike Swift", email: "valid@email.com", ... etc ...
```

OR

```
User.find(@user.id)
=> #<User id: 2, name: "Mike Swift", email: "valid@email.com", ... etc ...
```

Is there any real difference between the later three of these methods? (I already know `User.find(n)` would be the fastest) I would imagine they all work in about the same time, but perhaps I'm wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of sql they all do the same thing.

```
User.find(2)
```

This will be the fastest because there is no conversion needed.

Then `User.find(@user.id)` and `User.find(@user[:id])`.

And finally `User.find(@user` because rails needs convert the user to an ID.

Comment: I just updated the question. I already knew `User.find(n)` was the fastest. What is the difference between `@user.id` and `@user[:id]`?

Comment: @user.id means "call the method id on user". AR makes that method for you. You can override that method. @user[:id] means "call the [] method of user with 1 argument (:id)". AR makes this the same thing as @user.id, but again you can override the [] method.

Answer (score 0):

User.find(2) should be faster as Rails doesn't have to do any work to figure out the id.  The others require some level of message passing to get the id.

I doubt the difference is very significant though.

You could try all of them and look at your log to see how long it takes to get your response.

Comment: I actually already knew `User.find(2)` was the fastest. I meant the fastest between the later three options. I will clarify the question.